# Attach multiple addresses to one employee

Tags: orchardcms

I am creating a custom employee module. An employee can have up to three addresses. I am trying to follow this article - http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations

This is what I have in Migrations.cs.

```
 SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("EmployeeRecord",
        table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<int>("EmployeeId")
            ...
            .Column<int>("AddressRecord_Id")
        );


SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("AddressRecord",
    table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        ...
    );
```

Here are the models.

```
public class EmployeeRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public virtual int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual AddressRecord AddressRecord { get; set; }
}

public class AddressRecord {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

When create-new-employee form is submitted, I get the data with multiple addresses. I can create a new employee content type. But I am not sure how to create and assign the three addresses to that employee. 
Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You got the basics of your model wrong: if employee has addresses, it's the address that should point to an employee, and not the employee to the address. Unless you really never will have more than three, in which case you could have Address1, Address2 and Address3 properties. In any case, I'd recommend reading a bit more about the representation of relationships in relational databases before you proceed.

Comment: I was not thinking about the underlying database design. I was trying to follow the article as closely as I can. Is there any other example on implementing 1-n relationship in Orchard? The Address/State example in the above link was not very helpful.

Comment: Well, that's not following the article closely at all, seeing that you got the relationship backwards whereas the article got it right. Can you explain how the article is not helpful so that I know what you're expecting?

Comment: The article is not easy follow, Address/States is not a good example for 1-n relationship. This is what I see in the article, AddressPartRecord has StateRecord, and AddressPartRecord table has StateRecord_Id.
`code`  
    public class AddressPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    ...
    public virtual StateRecord StateRecord { get; set; }
    ...
    }
  
    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("AddressPartRecord",
    table => table
    ...
    .Column<int>("StateRecord_Id")
    ...
    );  `code`

Comment: The documentation is on github, and anybody can contribute. If you think it's a bad article, please feel free to make it better.
I don't understand how address/state is not a good example for 1-n.

Comment: As address has one state. I feel the author could have used something else for illustrating one-to-many relationship. Can you please comment on the AddressPartRecord and the table structure.

Comment: I'm the author. Each state is associated with n addresses. If you read further, you'll see that there is also an example of a many-to-many relationship.